# Enable SSL and add certificate programatically in Embedded Apache Tomcat 9

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat

I have the following code to start my software:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // set system property for exit on failure
    System.setProperty("org.apache.catalina.startup.EXIT_ON_INIT_FAILURE", "true");

    // create tomcat
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();

    // create connector, configure and add to tomcat
    Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
    connector.setMaxPostSize(-1);
    connector.setPort(8080);
    connector.setURIEncoding("UTF-8");
    ((Http11NioProtocol)connector.getProtocolHandler()).setConnectionUploadTimeout(36000000);
    ((Http11NioProtocol)connector.getProtocolHandler()).setDisableUploadTimeout(false);
    ((Http11NioProtocol)connector.getProtocolHandler()).setConnectionTimeout(3600000);
    ((Http11NioProtocol)connector.getProtocolHandler()).setCompression("on");
    ((Http11NioProtocol)connector.getProtocolHandler()).setCompressibleMimeType("text/html,text/xml,text/plain,application/javascript");
    tomcat.setConnector(connector);

    // add web app with jsps and servlets
    StandardContext standardContext = (StandardContext)tomcat.addWebapp("", new File(".").getAbsolutePath()+"/src/webroot");
    standardContext.getJarScanner().setJarScanFilter(new JarScanFilter() { @Override public boolean check(JarScanType jarScanType, String s) {
        if(s != null){
            if(s.startsWith("mchange-commons-java")){
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }});
    standardContext.setParentClassLoader(Run.class.getClassLoader());
    WebResourceRoot webResourceRoot = new StandardRoot(standardContext);
    File additionWebInfClassesFolder = new File(new File(".").getAbsolutePath(), "target/classes");
    WebResourceSet webResourceSet = new DirResourceSet(webResourceRoot, "/WEB-INF/classes", additionWebInfClassesFolder.getAbsolutePath(), "/");
    webResourceRoot.addPreResources(webResourceSet);
    standardContext.setResources(webResourceRoot);

    // start tomcat
    tomcat.start();

    // stay in this method as long as tomcat is running
    tomcat.getServer().await();
}
```

Now I have my certificate files (private key, certificate) and I want to add SSL functionality to this Tomcat Server. I know that this might not be best practice, but I am looking for a very simple way to do that. I know I can create a keystore file and add the properties to the connector but what I basically want is to have a string with my certificate content and apply that.

Answer (score 3):

My solution winds up looking a lot like the code I finally stumbled upon here to help me fix my issues: https://github.com/OryxProject/oryx/blob/master/framework/oryx-lambda-serving/src/main/java/com/cloudera/oryx/lambda/serving/ServingLayer.java#L202

Note: I believe I am using Tomcat 10.

```
    private Connector createSslConnector(){
       Connector httpsConnector = new Connector();
       httpsConnector.setPort(443);
       httpsConnector.setSecure(true);
       httpsConnector.setScheme("https");
       httpsConnector.setAttribute("SSLEnabled", "true");

       SSLHostConfig sslConfig = new SSLHostConfig();

       SSLHostConfigCertificate certConfig = new SSLHostConfigCertificate(sslConfig, SSLHostConfigCertificate.Type.RSA);
       certConfig.setCertificateKeystoreFile("/root/.keystore");
       certConfig.setCertificateKeystorePassword("changeit");
       certConfig.setCertificateKeyAlias("mykeyalias");
       sslConfig.addCertificate(certConfig);

       httpsConnector.addSslHostConfig(sslConfig);

       return httpsConnector;
}
```